# How to do role based URL authorization?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

Java 8 + Spring MVC 4

I am learning to the programme and came across one scenario.

There are different roles

1) Admin

```
 i)  ABC Admin 

ii)  XYZ Admin
```

2) Normal

ABC Admin logged into the system and created a contract, with contract_id: 123

Edit URL is : `localhost:8080/myApp/contract/edit/123`

XYZ Admin logged into the system and copy pasted above edit URL in the browser.
(Ideally, XYZ Admin should not be able to edit the ABC admin contracts and vice versa)

I need some suggestions/ideas what should I use for this.

I did a search on google and got spring security will be the fit case for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')")` for access multiple role on a single method

or

`@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")` for only one role on method level in Controller/DAO classes.